# How to get latlng of selected marker in zoomend event?

Tags: leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet, I have many markers in the map, I want to see more detail of a marker by selecting a marker and to do zoom-in and out, I expect to keep the selected marker to stay on the center of the map when it’s zoomed-in and out but I can’t.

I try to do the following js in the “zoomend” event but the js code requires the latlng value to center the selected marker.

```
mymap.on('zoomend', onZoomEnd);

 function onZoomEnd(e)
 {
     console.log("here.onZoomEnd");

     // How to get the latlng of selected marker?

     var latLngs = [e.target.getLatLng()];
   
     var markerBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngs);
   
     mymap.fitBounds(markerBounds);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect to keep the selected marker to stay on the center of the map when it’s zoomed-in and out

Set the map's `maxBounds` to cover just the marker's location, i.e.:

```
map.setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(marker.getLatLng(), marker.getLatLng()));
```